# Post swf in user facebook timeline not working

Tags: php, facebook, flash, facebook-sdk-3.0

I want to post swf file within user Facebook timeline but seems I am missing something. Only image is display not the swf file. Plz help what I am doing worng

```
var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          link: 'share-page.php',
          picture: 'uploads/pics/a.png',
          source: 'assets/swf/preloader.swf',
          name : 'name',
          caption: 'Caption',
          description: 'Description'
        };

        function callback(response) {
          //some code here
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

And my share-page.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />


<!-- Open grah tags for Facebook -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Test video player" />
<meta property="og:description" content="A video player interface experiment." />
<meta property="og:type" content="video" />
<meta property="og:url" content="share-page.php"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="uploads/pics/a.png"/>
<meta property="og:video" content="assets/swf/preloader.swf" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="assets/swf/preloader.swf" />  <meta property="og:video:width" content="325" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="180" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish I saw your question sooner...

See my answer to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367646/how-to-embed-my-own-flash-video-player-in-facebook)** and hopefully it will help you.

Your main issue is you just put folder names (Assets and Uploads) without even saying what website/server they come from. You need a full path to files:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.yoursite.com/share-page.php"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.yoursite.com/uploads/pics/a.png" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.yoursite.com/assets/swf/preloader.swf" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="HTTPS://www.yoursite.com/assets/swf/preloader.swf" />
```

Basically you should be able to paste exact same path into a new browser tab and see a working result otherwise it wont work anywhere else including Facebook. Also you need the SWF file mentioned in both **"og:video"** and **"og:video:secure_url"** tags to be coming from a genuine HTTPS server or it won't run within your timeline post (instead it opens new tab to your link).

`Only image is display` sounds like a lucky mistake!! Most likely because in your wall you're posting a link to your html page? Just so happens that Facebook also scans such links for a display image (It's usually random but I guess for you the shown pic WAS the only one available to find there??)