# How to embed custom HTML5 Player on Facebook post?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, youtube

Thanks for reading my question

I've googled enough to die, to find how to embed custom HTML5 Player on Facebook post. I've seen Youtube, Soundcloud, (and recently Sketchfab).. links when share on Facebook, it will be transformed into HTML5 player. I knew how to embed custom Flash player, but it's really hard to embed custom HTML5 player.

I've tried to use all OG tag they (Youtube, Sketchfab) used, I bought SSL certificate to have HTTPS url, ... but when share on Facebook, my link won't transform to HTML5 player...

Maybe only selected companies can use this feature?

Thanks a lot

Comment: They are testing it. When it becomes available for everyone it will be announced on developers.facebook.com

Comment: @WizKid Thanks, is there any source for this? Actually, I've embed html5 successfully 2 weeks ago, but cannot do again on next day. Seems they opened for 1 day then closed

Comment: If you search developers.facebook.com it is not documented there. And I work at Facebook

Comment: _“Actually, I've embed html5 successfully 2 weeks ago”_ – I seriously doubt that …

Comment: @CBroe yes, exactly. FB display my links with Play icon. Clicking it will load my HTML page inside iframe (like Youtube links now). I was so happy and call my client about it, but it became normal on next day, no ideas.


I used this og tag

<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html">

Comment: @WizKid any news / ETA on this ? thanks

Comment: No. We will post on developers.facebook.com when it becomes available

Comment: @Dada: Not that I know of

Comment: Also, I'm watching that also another "itseez3D" is using an custom HTML5 viewer on Facebook (https://www.facebook.com/itseez3D/) to show 3D Models. How is possibile to make it?

Comment: No. When/if anyone can use it it will be announced on developers.Facebook.com

Comment: Any news?? Why youtube, vimeo, gliphy can add their own custom player?

Comment: http://www.zdnet.com/article/facebook-switches-to-html5-for-all-video-instead-of-flash/    Does this mean we can start custom HTML5 embeds now @WizKid ??

Comment: No. Why do you think that?

Comment: I think this is an agreement made between companies. So if a youtube link is detected, then it is embedded into a player. It should not be allowed to embed whatever code for security reasons. There could be code injection in the web and open the possibility to attack facebook users viewing that media source. So it should be internally converted by facebook, not by adding html or javascript code.

Comment: This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367646/how-to-embed-my-own-flash-video-player-in-facebook

Comment: if you look at this article: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music, it says that custom  players are only available to whitelisted companies. So, I assume that should also apply to html5 player.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't allow this at present, and for good reason. If it were opened up to developers it would likely be a cross-site scripting nightmare. They've likely written parsers in-house to do this themselves. You could probably do hinting for things like what image should be displayed on an article, but as for embedding anything (running Javascript on top of Facebook), good luck without something like a custom Chrome extension.