# How to embed a iframe player in FB's wall?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, kaltura

I been trying to embed a iframe player on FB with OG tags unsuccessfully.  But I found that [Kaltura](http://player.kaltura.com/docs/Share) player cans. I'been trying to copy what they did, but couldn't make it work.

[Here](http://player.kaltura.com/docs/Share) and [here](https://blog.kaltura.org/facebook-now-require-html5-and-fallback-in-open-graph) Kaltura explains how to embed their player in FB. Basically they say that you should put the following tags:

```
 <!-- Facebook iframe embed  -->
 <meta property="og:video:url" content="https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/243342/sp/24334200/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/28685261/partner_id/243342?iframeembed=true&playerId=kaltura_player&entry_id=1_sf5ovm7u">
 <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/243342/sp/24334200/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/28685261/partner_id/243342?iframeembed=true&playerId=kaltura_player&entry_id=1_sf5ovm7u&">
 <meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html">
 <meta property="og:video:width" content="560">
 <meta property="og:video:height" content="395">
```

Of course I tried that and many other things, like coping Kaltura Http headers. But it did not work, any clue why it works for them? What I'm missing?

**Note:** This is a duplicated [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776610/how-to-embed-custom-html5-player-on-facebook-post), but I wanted to add this Kaltura exception that I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply follow [this example](http://player.kaltura.com/modules/KalturaSupport/components/share/Share.html).

**Edit**
Just noticed u tried it. It should and does work if u include the tags correctly.

Are u using Kaltura.com or your own self hosted?
Facebook as well as twitter, embed.ly and other embed destinations require white listing of the embed provider URLs. So if you are self hosting your Kaltura server, it should be noted that you also need to contact these services (e.g. facebook) to be white listed.

Comment: Ah! so that's why it works. Because is Kaltura is FB withelisted! Thanks! Do you know how to Contact FB to be whitelisted? I could not find any program for that.

Comment: do you know any provider that is whitelisted in FB, that can help me to embed my player in FB post?

Comment: also (https://www.facebook.com/itseez3D/) is using custom player; i don't know how is possibile.

Comment: @zohar.babin Do you know how to be withelisted in FB?