# How to make a "share button" for my android app (Adobe air)?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

How do I make a "Share Button" in my android app which is supported by Adobe Air, Action Script 3.0.

I want to add a costum text, for example: 
"*Download this app, something-something, www.mywebsite.com*."

I want to share it on: Whatsapp.

So.. What should I do?

Comment: In that case make sure **www.mywebsite.com** has Oembed or OpenGraph meta tags in the html. I dont know about WhatsApp but Twitter and Facebook use the OG tags. Here is **[one example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367646/how-to-embed-my-own-flash-video-player-in-facebook/26399297#26399297)** where I answer such question (forget video part, you only need that "image__src" for custom image). All these sites are looking to share your own HTML page so maybe google search what each sites  expects to find in your html code for custom texts/image for shared URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use air native extension 
try this one

https://github.com/illuzor/Android-Sharing-Extension-ANE

there are many other extensions but I used this one and it works fine

Comment: Sorry if I sound dumb, but what are Native extensons? and how do I put them?

Comment: @BhaveshShaha, whats wrong with official Facebook way of using **sharer.php**? Your wall post will have to be a link to something, an html page. For custom image & text make sure that html page gives that relevant info to Facebook via OG tags in the html. Then in your app you make a button to open browser page: **https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://yourwebsite.com/page_to_share.html**.. the text and image will appear automatically if **page_to_share.html** has OG tags. Google search how to add them to your HTML page that you want to share. No success if you dont try..

Comment: For example: Make a button in your flash app to open new browser window. This is the link it must open: (copy& paste the address) : **[test link](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://vcone.co.uk/inter/rt_wave_vocal/index.html)**.. where the image & text come from? for that see the html source of the shared page: **[view-source](http://vcone.co.uk/inter/rt_wave_vocal/index.html)**. Between that example and Google you should be okay

Comment: Edited the question. Whatsapp is much more important than fb.

Comment: Native Extensions for Adobe AIR are code libraries that contain native code wrapped with an ActionScript API. Or in simple words is an (.ane) file that contains (java)  library to be called by an adobe air application for functions that are not supported by (action script) alone. for more info see http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html or http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/index.html

Comment: How do I add them in my Adobe Flash?

Comment: Read this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS597e5dadb9cc1e0253f7d2fc1311b491071-8000.html#WSb2a114358507af456b18bc461311b6bc0a8-7ffd

Comment: I have done that. But now, how do I add the actions? and connect that with a mouse event property?